# Can I safely run a virus using sandboxie?

Tags: virus, sandbox

I want to test some untrusted software to check them, for this reason, I researched for a good sandbox software and I found [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/DownloadSandboxie) I tested few safe application, but I am not sure if I can run untrusted application also?

Comment: It is going to depend entirely on what the malware does.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your risk tolerance. I've done it before with no ill effects, but the gold standard for this sort of thing is to use a virtual machine.

Sandboxie is a solution that avoids the need for a fully virtualized machine by wrapping the userspace APIs that programs have access to. Unless they've screwed up and missed one, that'll do the trick -- but the available attack surface is much less well-documented and there's a lot less defense in depth than a VM.

If you're using a recent Windows 10 build, you can install the Windows Sandbox (just run OptionalFeatures.exe and check the box), a very nice and speedy VM just for this sort of thing. Once it's installed, you can just cut-n'-paste the suspect file in there and see what happens. However, closing it will clear the sandbox; Sandboxie can retain state if you want it to, which can be useful sometimes.